# Remove comments when publishing production build

Tags: reactjs, asp.net, asp.net-core, production

Is there an option that in the publish stage I can remove all comments that exist in the project?
Meaning they will still be in the project but will be removed in prod build?
I need to do this in both react and asp.net core projects.

Comment: Usually, Production builds removes comments. You don't need to do anything specific for this.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, AFAIK, this is not possible. I stumbled on to this question while searching myself - AGAIN - after years of working with Visual Studio. JS minimized files have comments removed, but .vbhtml files (using MVC at the moment) JS comments still find their way to production code during publish. It makes no sense to me to not have the ability to do this, especially if you are precompiling .vbhtml files prior to publish. Please do post any updates with positive findings if you can.